# JVM restarts automatically

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, logging, tomcat5.5

when cpu reaches 100% my jvm restarts automatically with following error message.why it happens ???

**Error:**

```
ERROR | wrapper | 2012/04/05 20:00:31 | Shutdown failed: Timed out waiting for signal from JVM.
ERROR | wrapper | 2012/04/05 20:00:31 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
STATUS | wrapper | 2012/04/05 20:00:36 | Launching a JVM...
INFO | jvm 4 | 2012/04/05 20:00:38 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO | jvm 4 | 2012/04/05 20:00:43 | Apr 5, 2012 8:00:43 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol init
    INFO | jvm 4 | 2012/04/05 20:00:43 | INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8181
    INFO | jvm 4 | 2012/04/05 20:00:43 | Apr 5, 2012 8:00:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO | jvm 4 | 2012/04/05 20:00:43 | INFO: Initialization processed in 2375 ms
    INFO | jvm 4 | 2012/04/05 20:00:43 | Apr 5, 2012 8:00:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
    INFO | jvm 4 | 2012/04/05 20:00:43 | INFO: Starting service Catalina
    INFO | jvm 4 | 2012/04/05 20:00:43 | Apr 5, 2012 8:00:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
    INFO | jvm 4 | 2012/04/05 20:00:43 | INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.5.25
    INFO | jvm 4 | 2012/04/05 20:00:44 | Apr 5, 2012 8:00:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start
```

Comment: No error thrown other than above

Comment: INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/04/03 13:11:49 | Wrapper Process has not received any CPU time for 21 seconds.  Extending timeouts.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/04/03 13:12:20 | Shutdown failed: Timed out waiting for signal from JVM.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/04/03 13:12:20 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/04/03 13:12:25 | Launching a JVM...

Comment: How will your JVM beeing started?

Comment: actually, before CPU reaches 100%, the it should throw PermgenSpace error. But it is not throwing, so something malfunction happened with your memory allocation for Tomcat server.

Comment: @tusar it happens only now before no such problem occurs...

Comment: After googling https://forums.manageengine.com/topic/wrapper-error but it also not give proper solution

Comment: @tusar, why it should? PermGenSpace error only thrown when you are running out of permanent generation memory space. This is not always the case.

Answer (score 2):

This is not JVM that is restarting. It is the wrapper script that you are using is shutting down it and starts again. This is how it is configured. Looks your application does a lot of CPU usage. You may try to go through both heap dumps and GC logs to see if it's related to garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you did not specify any memory configuration for Tomcat. My guess is  Tomcat is using whatever memory it needed to execute all the requests. And as I told before, Tomcat should throw a PermgenSpace error when it consumes maximum available memory, before CPU reaches 100%. (And then you need to manually restart of course.) This scenario can be avoided if you set up a [predefined memory configuration for tomcat server](http://www.coderanch.com/t/87422/Tomcat/increase-java-heap-size).

Also if you are loading your application with `<Context>` then specifying `reloadable="false"` also makes the Tomcat not to reload the context automatically.

Comment: @ahanin, you can post a different question on SO about that, I would try to attempt that. Here I am helping the OP with whatever I have experienced in my day-to-day works. I fail to notice any importance of your comment with regards to OP's problem.